# beforeRouteEnter infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm having this problem with Vue Router.

My scenario is to allow `/` to be loaded first, fetch some data from there and then it will go to `/chat/:chatId` route and render UI there, where `:chatId` param is set from the data I got from API.

I have `/` and `['chat', 'chat/:chatId']` as route alias.

I have in-component guard for this matter.

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  store.dispatch('fetchOpenSessions')
  .then(() => {
    const firstChat = Object.keys(store.state.chatsidebar.openSessions)[0];
    next({ name: 'chat', params: { chatId: firstChat } });
  });
},
```

However this code ends up looping infinitely, causing the browser to hang.

My question is, how do I set `chat/:chatId` if my initial route is `/` or `/chat` without getting into infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    store.dispatch('fetchOpenSessions')
        .then(() => {
            if(to.name == 'chat'){
                next();
            }else{
                const firstChat = Object.keys(store.state.chatsidebar.openSessions)[0];
                next({ name: 'chat', params: { chatId: firstChat } });
            }
        });
},
```

Comment: Wow. That makes sense. Thanks for your answer. I will accept it once 5 mins had passed! :)